# How do I make animated subtitles to go with music?

Tags: subtitles

The subtitles in this video look amazing.  They are able to make the words dissolve and fall off the screen as the song progresses.  Most subtitles are just plain text.  How is it possible to make animated sub-titles?  Are there any ways to make it match up with the music quickly or is it a manual process?

[image]

Comment: I have given a pass at trying to generalize the question a bit more.  In general, I think the question of how to make burnt in custom subtitles that are animated in general, as well as any tricks to sync that animation to music would be of general interest.  I agree that there is less general benefit in addressing the specific look of the effect, but there is a broader, more general question here that still merits an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The author of the subtitles, Jefferz, says:

> "... I animated the text to match the original subtitles use Adobe After Effects (CS6 specifically) keyframing the text movements ...".

Source [Jefferz's Tumblr Blog](http://jefferzkm.tumblr.com/page/11).

It's a manual process.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy with Adobe After Effects or other linear editors.  Build your text block. Set it's track and timing, and apply the fades at the appropriate points on the timeline